# Stretch BindableLayout.ItemTemplate in Maui horizontally

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a `HorizontalStackLayout` with elements in it added via the `BindableLayout.Itemsource`.

This is an example of what I mean:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StackLayoutStretchTest.MainPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               BackgroundColor="Green">
            <BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                    <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
             <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        TextColor="White"
                        BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Text"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   BackgroundColor="White"/>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Example]

How can I make the Labels(Blue) FillAndExpand into the free space(Green)?
The Maui learn page says:

> A `HorizontalStackLayout` only respects the alignment preferences on
> child views that are in the opposite direction to the orientation of
> the layout.

Is there a way to stretch the children, or what is the appropriate "container" for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that it's a known issue that being tracked in [[Bug] LayoutOptions Expand not work in HorizontalStackLayout and VerticalStackLayout](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6031) . To be clear, the `AndExpand` options are deprecated, and are not supported in the new `HorizontalStackLayout` and `VerticalStackLayout`. As an alternative solution, you can achieve the same layout with a `Grid`. Or you can continue to use `StackLayout` for another choice.

Comment: How would you make the ListView stretch in Grid? I'm running into the same issue and that's what I'm using. `<ListView x:Name="lst" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">` in a two-column `Grid` still only goes right as far as the text in it.